# Need help with standalone circuit; atmega328p and WS2812

Tags: led, pcb, atmega328p, ws2812b

I have a problem involving those two modules, can't keep them work together in board for more than 30 secs. Randomly, leds WS2812D-F5 w/ WS2812B-B, starts to turn on when should be off and then all goes on full white making useless the chinese version atMega328P U TQFP32.

Have tested both separately and worked fine, the leds with an external Arduino with welded jumpers on board, and the MC with blink. But... I'm only been able to program, via ISCP, the MC only when the Led module isn't welded.

1. Why would the MC has been able to program without connecting the signal (digitalPin 10) to leds?
2. Why would the leds produce such randomness and procede to anihilate the MC only when it is connected?

[image: Schematic of both modules]

Comment: what are U$3 and U$4?

Comment: DIP Leds , ws2812d-f5

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have 3 (three) different nets for GND. Try connecting them together and your circuit will be fine.

Comment: Hi, I used a GND plane. They're all connected.